# Policy or script to disable MS Edge pop-ups in Windows 10

Tags: group-policy, windows-10, microsoft-edge

Is it possible to disable MS Edge pop-ups in Windows 10 for all users using group policy / registry settings?

After installing Edge (through upgrade to 20H2) I've seen pop-ups like these:

1. [system tray pop-up - browse internet with Microsoft Edge, new browser recommended by Microsoft for your computer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gV4DD.png)
2. [taskbar pop-up - the new MS Edge is here, get back to browsing straight from your taskbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IS6ps.png) (mentioned [here](https://www.forbes.com/sites/barrycollins/2020/09/24/windows-10-nagging-to-install-edge-is-getting-worse-and-worse/?sh=3c48a42e3c15) with news it will be worse in 21H1)

It would be great to get rid of those (and others too e.g. ["Get the New Microsoft Edge" Popups](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/discussions/quot-get-the-new-microsoft-edge-quot-popups/m-p/1492356)). I've enabled policy [HideFirstRunExperience](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-policies#hidefirstrunexperience), but it didn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can enable the following 2 policies, both in **Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\cloud Content\**

"Do not show Windows Tips"

> This policy setting prevents Windows tips from being shown to users.
> If you enable this policy setting, users will no longer see Windows tips[...]

and

"Turn off Microsoft consumer experiences"

> This policy setting turns off experiences that help consumers make the most of their devices and Microsoft account.
> If you enable this policy setting, users will no longer see personalized recommendations from Microsoft and notifications about their Microsoft account. [...]

Note that the second one is available only if you are using Windows 10 Enterprise or Education

Comment: First one also is rather limited on Windows 10 Pro. Do you know a way to achieve effect of these policies without Windows 10 Enterprise/Education?

Comment: Oh yes, indeed, both are restricted to Win10 Enterprise... These policies are ignored by Windows 10 Pro, I'm not aware of any other supported way, however, take a look at the corresponding setting in Settings -> System -> Notifications & Actions -> "Show me the Windows welcome experience after update[...]" maybe try to uncheck the box and Procmon to see where Windows writes this preference.

Comment: The key for "Show me the Windows welcome experience..." is HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ContentDeliveryManager (SubscribedContent-310093Enabled), but setting it didn't make Edge ads go away (I also tried disabling the same way "Suggest ways I can finish setting up my device..." and "Get tips, tricks and suggestions...". At least the pop-ups seem to be shown only once (at least until next upgrade).